# Issue calculating table scrollbar location

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

So I have a script that adds a slight shadow to table edge where you can scroll, depending on the location of the scrollbar, but it sometimes doesn't work.

This is one part of it:

```
  $('table').on('scrollstart scrollstop', function(){
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('table-wrap')){
      var elem = $(this),
        elemBody = elem.find('tbody'),
        elemParent = elem.parent('.table-wrap');
      var scrolled = (elemBody.outerWidth() - elemParent.outerWidth() - elem.scrollLeft());
      if(scrolled === 0){
        elemParent.addClass('left_active');
        elemParent.removeClass('right_active');
      } else if(elem.scrollLeft() === 0) {
        elemParent.removeClass('left_active');
        elemParent.addClass('right_active');
      } else {
        elemParent.addClass('left_active');
        elemParent.addClass('right_active');
      }
    }
  });
```

This part sometimes I have to add "+1" to "`elem.scrollLeft()` --here---); to make it work.

> var scrolled = (elemBody.outerWidth() - elemParent.outerWidth() -
>   elem.scrollLeft());

But then I noticed,  some tables it helps and on others, it stops working. Meaning when I scroll to right the '`right_active`' class will not disappear.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle to work on ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including scrollbar width in your calculation for `var scrolled`?

```
var scrolled = (elemBody.outerWidth() - elemParent.outerWidth() - elem.scrollLeft());
```

I think you are on the right track but the width is probably not precise since `.outerWidth()` doesn't include scrollbar width. Hence, the maximum scroll width is always greater than the actual element width.